# Why are all my bean properties null when when running jsp file

Tags: java, html, jsp, netbeans, javabeans

I'm trying to make a database login.  I have a bean with properties url, username, and password; an html page with the login parameters (a combobox with the url, and input text fields for username and password); and a jsp to process the request. When I run the jsp, all the properties from the bean remain null. I've ran it through the debugger and I can see they're all null.

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
    <form method = "post" action = "DBLoginInitialization.jsp">
        JDBC URL
        <select name = "url" size = "1">
            <option>jdbc:mysql://localhost/javabook</option>
        </select><br /><br />
            Username <input name = "username" /><br /><br />
            Password <input name = "password" /><br /><br />
        <input type = "submit" name = "Submit" value = "Login" />
        <input type = "reset" value = "Reset" />
    </form>
```

Here's part of my bean:

```
    public class DBBean implements java.io.Serializable{
        private Connection connection = null;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private String url;
        private String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

       /** Initialize Database */
       public void initializeDB() {
           try {
                Class.forName(driver);

                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
           }
           catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
  }
```

And JSP:

```
    <%@page import = "database.DBBean" %>
    <jsp:useBean id = "dbBeanId" scope = "session" 
                      class = "database.DBBean" ></jsp:useBean>
    <jsp:setProperty name = "dbBeanId" property = "*" />

    <body>

        <%-- Problem occurs here when trying to initialize database--%>
        <% dbBeanId.initializeDB(); %>

        <% if (dbBeanId.getConnection() == null) { %>
            Error: Login Failed. Try Again
        <% } 
           else { %>
                <jsp:forward page = "Table.jsp" />
        <% } %>

    </body>
```

I can't figure out why all my properties are null when trying to intializeDB().
EDIT: all the getter and setter methods are in place.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have properties, but only private fields. Create getters and setters to make bean properties out of them!

Comment: You weren't completely off. There WAS something wrong with my get and set methods. +1